# With paypal checkout, what info can we get using their API?

Tags: paypal

If someone checks out and pays on paypal's site, what information can I get back from my transaction?

Do they have an API where I can pull all orders for the month, and can I get the customers information also?

Answer (score 2):

> I've found: Easy-to-Read Reports
>
> View a summary of your account
>   activity each month, including monthly
>   sales, transaction details, and profit
>   and loss.

Link: https://merchant.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/express_checkout

Which suggests that you can pull orders for the month, but I don't know if they're talking about doing it via the API or just their website. Were you wanting to do it only via the API?

---

Well, you *can* get information about the buyer, and also information about the order. I've found this URL, I will update my answer when I find out if you can pull orders for the month or not:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro

If you scroll down to "A Sample IPN Message and Response", it lists all the stuff you can get back from PayPal after the payment is copmleted.

I'll keep looking for more info, but I think that's pretty much it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found this. It contains info on IPN History, but it looks like you can only so it via their website: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNOperations#id095RA08N05Z

Comment: I still can't find any more information on this. I'll come back to this thread if I find out more in the future, sorry I couldn't be of more help.